# Javascript function to rotate some div elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, setinterval

I have some javascript function - shows me a popup with some texts. I try to rotate two "section" elements, but if I add to HTML one more section with class custom, the page shows only first element. Please, help me to add 1-2 more  elements and to rotate it. The idea is to have 2 or more elements with class custom and to show it in random order, after last to stop. Thanks.

```js
    setInterval(function () {
     $(".custom").stop().slideToggle('slow');
    }, 2000);
    $(".custom-close").click(function () {
     $(".custom-social-proof").stop().slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="custom">
     <div class="custom-notification">
      <div class="custom-notification-container">
       <div class="custom-notification-image-wrapper">
        <img src="checkbox.png">
       </div>
       <div class="custom-notification-content-wrapper">
        <p class="custom-notification-content">
         Some Text
        </p>
       </div>
    
      </div>
      <div class="custom-close"></div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Can you add more details about your question or create a working pen with complete code?

Comment: Rohit Mittal, I uploaded it here: http://rss-novini.net/11111.htm

Comment: The idea is to have 2 or more elements with class custom and to show it in random order, after last to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Set section display none of page load instead of first section. Check below code of second section:

```
<section class="custom" style=" display:none">
    <div class="custom-notification">
      <div class="custom-notification-container">
        <div class="custom-notification-image-wrapper">
          <img src="checkbox.png">
        </div>

        <div class="custom-notification-content-wrapper">
          <p class="custom-notification-content">
            Mario<br>si kupi <b>2</b> matraka  
            <small>predi 1 chas</small>
          </p>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="custom-close"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And you need to make modification in your jQuery code as below:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        var sectionShown = 0;
        var sectionNotShown = 0;
        $(".custom").each(function(i){
            if ($(this).css("display") == "block") {
                sectionShown = 1;
                $(this).slideToggle('slow');
            } else {
                if (sectionShown == 1) {
                    $(this).slideToggle('slow');
                    sectionShown = 0;
                    sectionNotShown = 1;
                }
            }
        });                
        if (sectionNotShown == 0) {
            $(".custom:first").slideToggle('slow');
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, Rohit Mittal. In this way are rotated 2 items, but if I add third or more, are rotated only the first and the last item. And not random.

Comment: I have updated my answer and I have also checked it. It is working fine. Hope you will be able to achieve your requirement after this ;).